# How to call and authenticate Google Cloud function with HTTPS trigger in PHP?

Tags: php, curl, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to call my google cloud function from my PHP project but everytime I do so, I get the following error:

`Error: Forbidden Your client does not have permission to get URL /test-function from this server.`

So it seems I need to authenticate but I have no idea how to do that. I have HTTPS enabled in the Google Cloud Function in the trigger settings.

Right now I am trying to echo the response after calling the function.

```
//The Cloud Function's trigger URL (edited for this purpose)
    $url = "https://mycloudfunctionurl/test-function";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

// Set so curl_exec returns the result instead of outputting it.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Get the response and close the channel.
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    echo "Printing response: \n\n";
    echo $response;
    curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you deployed the Cloud Function with "Require authentication" selected. If you do so, then you'll need to manage authorized users through Cloud IAM and invoke the call with the identify of an authorized user. You can see information about downloading and using a keyfile to do this:

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating

Depending on what your Cloud Function is doing, however, the answer may simply be to not require authentication (and you can choose to handle authentication and authorization within your function; for example, with an API key or any other desired approach). Obviously do what is needed from a security standpoint; but, if that's reasonable, then you don't have to do anything additiaional -- your PHP code should work as-is.

To go this route, you simply need to deploy your cloud function with "Allow authenticated invocations" selected instead.

If you're deploying from Cloud Console, then it's simply the radio button options under "Authentication", towards the bottom of the create function form.

If you're deploying using the gcloud command line tool, make sure to include the "--allow-unauthenticated" switch.

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/filesystem